# Using a countifs statement with 2nd criteria range uses multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, formula, countif

I'm using this `countifs` formula but my second criteria are searching against a range of multiple columns and I'm getting "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size" as an error message.

```
=COUNTIFS('CTA Raw'!A:A,A2,'CTA Raw'!F:N,F1)
```

Can someone provide a better formula for me? Essentially, my second criteria could be in multiple columns and want to count it wherever it is.

Your help is appreciated! Sescreenshotsts below

My raw data looks like this...

[image: Raw Data]

I want it to count and look like this...

[image: Table]

Comment: What Excel version do you have? also post some sample data. you can copy paste a screenshot

Comment: Ricardo, I added the screen shots. I'm using Google Sheets.

Comment: I haven't work with google sheets. You tagged it as Excel.

Comment: Assuming first output value is in G8: `=countif($B2:$D2,G$7)`; copy down and across. Someone far more clever than me (and there are _LOTS_ of them) will surely explain how to combine this with arrayformula.

Comment: Thanks.Your formula is what I'm using today as a workaround. you mentioned arrayformula - that's where I'm trying to get too.